# How to argue that some inequality is justifiable in order to maximize the well-being of the worst off in Rawls's theory of justice?

Tags: ethics, political-philosophy, justice, rawls

In context, I have to describe what we think is a just society by Rawls theory of justice. I want to try and use Scandinavia, for example, the Nordic Model as a representation as a just society. However, I lack the knowledge and don't know where to start... any advice on where to start? Does this question apply to Scandinavian countries - the Nordic Model?